# how to trigger shell script after pulling docker image successfully

Tags: docker, shell

I want to run shell script(bash) when my ec2 pull docker image successfully.

Is there any way I can try?

I just found "docker events" command, but I don't know how to trigger script with this.

Comment: How are you pulling the docker image?

Comment: on dockerhub. or aws ecr is fine.

Comment: just use "docker pull <>" command. 
ex) docker pull jiguy/server:0.0.1.


Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Is it your own command line, is it a hook, is a groovy-script, is it within a docker?